# Importing bulk json data into neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load json file of size about 700k. But it is showing me the heap memory out of space error.

My query is as below:

```
WITH "file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//tjson.json" as url  
call apoc.load.json(url) yield value as article return article
```

Like in csv I tried to use `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000` with json. But I am not allowed to use with loading json.

How to load bulk json data?.

Comment: So what is your main problem?

Comment: Are the query `call apoc.load.json(url) yield value as article return count(article)` return count of article?

Comment: I have 7lacs json data. when I am trying to load with above query into neo4j I am getting memory out of space error. so my main problem is how can I load these 700000 json data

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert JSON into CSV files using jq - a uber fast json converter. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/

This is the recommended way according to: https://neo4j.com/blog/bulk-data-import-neo4j-3-0/

If you have many files, write a python program or similar that iterates through the length of files calling:

```
os.system("cat file{}.json | jq '. [.entity1, .entity2, .entity3] | @csv' >> concatenatedCSV.csv".format(num))
```

or in Go:

```
exec.Command("cat file"+num+".json | jq '. [.entity1, .entity2, .entity3] | @csv' >> concatenatedCSV.csv")
```

I recently did this for about 700GB of JSON files. It takes some thought to get the csv files in the right format, but if you follow the tutorial on jq you'll pickup how to do it. Additionally, check out how the headers need to be and what not here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/

It took about a day to convert it all, but given the transaction overhead of using apoc, and the ability to reimport at anytime once the files are in the format it is worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

`apoc.load.json` now supports a [json-path](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_json_path) as a second parameter.

To get the first 1000 JSON objects from the array in the file, try this:

```
WITH "file:///path_to_file.json" as url  
CALL apoc.load.json(url, '[0:1000]') YIELD value AS article
RETURN article;
```

The `[0:1000]` syntax specifies a range of array indices, and the second number is exclusive (so, in this example, the last index in the range is 999).

The above should at least work in neo4j 3.1.3 (with apoc [release 3.1.3.6](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/3.1.3.6)). Note also that the Desktop versions of neo4j (installed via the Windows and OSX installers) have a [new requirement](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#download-latest-release) concerning where to put plugins like apoc in order to import local files.